# How to get only the first match of a regex Grok filter

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

**goal**

I want to retrieve only this string "14" from this message with a logstash Grok

```
3/03/0 EE 14 GFR 20 AAA XXXXX 50 3365.00
```

**this is my grok code**

```
grok{
 match => {
        field1 => [
          "(?<number_extract>\d{0}\s\d{1,3}\s{1})"       
        ]         
      }
}
```

I would like to match just the first match "14" but my Grok filter returns all matches:

```
14 20 50
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to find the first occurrence of a number that consists of 1, 2 or 3 digits only, you may use

```
^(?:.*?\s)?(?<number_extract>\d{1,3})(?!\S)
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:.*?\s)?` - an optional substring of any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible, and then a whitespace (this enables a match at the start of the string if it is there)
- `(?<number_extract>\d{1,3})` - 1 to 3 digits
- `(?!\S)` - a negative lookahead that makes sure there is a whitespace or end of string immediately to the right (enables a match at the end of the string).

**Alternative solution**

If you know that the number you are looking for is after a date-like field and another field, and you want to force this pre-validation, you may use

```
^\d+/\d+/\d+\s+\S+\s+(?<number_extract>\d+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tyGAcO/1)

If you do not have to check if the first field is date-like, you may simply use

```
^\S+\s+\S+\s+(?<number_extract>\d+)
^(?:\S+\s+){2}(?<number_extract>\d+) // Equivalent
```

See [the regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/tyGAcO/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\d+/\d+/\d+` - 1+ digits, `/`, 1+ digits, `/`, 1+ digits
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `\S+` - 1+ chars other than whitespace
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?<number_extract>\d+)` - Capturing group "number_extract": 1+ digits.

Grok demo:

[image]